# Production build of react application missing few folders

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, yarnpkg, antd

I have an application build using react with ant design framework. The application runs perfectly fine in my local. The issue is when I give a build and deploy it on server few folders go missing in the build folder as a result the application doesnt run. This is how the code structure looks like

[Code folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaSlE.png)

After I build the code the following structure is given

[build folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Bon.png)

As you can see I am missing a folder, as a result i get the following error

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPjTV.png)

The router code is

```
<Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path={`${url}`}
      component={asyncComponent(() => import("../AdminHome"))}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path={`${url}/edit-role`}
      component={asyncComponent(() => import("../AdminHome/EditRole"))}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path={`${url}/clients`}
      component={asyncComponent(() => import("../MdmClient/home"))}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path={`${url}/clients/edit`}
      component={asyncComponent(() => import("../MdmClient/EditClient"))}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path={`${url}/clients/add`}
      component={asyncComponent(() => import("../MdmClient/AddClient"))}
    />
  </Switch>
```

Code asyncComponent is

```
export default function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
class AsyncFunc extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            component: null
        };
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        Nprogress.start();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.mounted = false;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.mounted = true;
        const { default: Component } = await importComponent();
        Nprogress.done();
        if (this.mounted) {
            this.setState({
                component: <Component {...this.props} />
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const Component = this.state.component || <div />;
        return (
            <ReactPlaceholder type="text" rows={7} ready={Component !== null}>
                {Component}
            </ReactPlaceholder>
        );
    }
}
return AsyncFunc;
}
```

I am stuck for a week I have tried everything I could find on internet but nothing works. Any help is appreciated.

.gitignore code below

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about 
ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Comment: Did you try to build locally and it works fine? I guess you failing on deploying and not on building? Try showing your `.gitignore`

Comment: Correct it builds fine without issue but on deploying there is a folder missing and i get 404 errors in console. so maybe i am guessing while building its ignore some files.